# Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet? and not able to run npm start

Tags: node.js

I am facing the above error and I am unable to run npm start after using npm audit fix --

force .Please resolve the issue

Windows PowerShell

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements!
https://aka.ms/PSWindows

PS C:\Users\nahee\OneDrive\Desktop> cd MERN_PROJECT

PS C:\Users\nahee\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN_PROJECT> cd animal-feedmart

PS C:\Users\nahee\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN_PROJECT\animal-feedmart> npm

start

> animal-feedmart@1.0.0 start

> expo start

Starting project at

C:\Users\nahee\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN_PROJECT\animal-feedmart

Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install

yet?

PS C:\Users\nahee\OneDrive\Desktop\MERN_PROJECT\animal-feedmart>

I am unable to share the picture so i am showing my terminal how it

looks when I use npm start command

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to `npm init` then `npm install expo` then `npm start` if am not wrong. Please provide more info by screenshot or something.

Or remove `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and do the above commands

Comment: Should I use all these commands inside my project terminal or in cmd?? And  if I remove package-lock.json will be any problem for my project??

Comment: There won't be an issue. but do not remove packga.json